# Filter a DataFrame by comparing dates from two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
   Publication Date        Date  Value State
0        2018-12-12  2018-12-11    2.0    AL
1        2018-12-12  2018-12-11    1.0    AZ
2        2018-12-12  2018-12-11    1.0    AK
3        2018-12-12  2018-12-11    2.0    NJ
4        2018-12-12  2018-12-11    1.5    NY
5        2018-12-12  2018-12-12   12.0    AL
6        2018-12-12  2018-12-12   13.0    AZ
7        2018-12-12  2018-12-12   14.0    AK
8        2018-12-12  2018-12-12   12.0    NJ
9        2018-12-12  2018-12-12   11.5    NY
10       2018-12-13  2018-12-12    2.0    AL
11       2018-12-13  2018-12-12    3.0    AZ
12       2018-12-13  2018-12-12    6.0    AK
13       2018-12-13  2018-12-12    1.0    NJ
14       2018-12-13  2018-12-12    4.0    NY
```

I want to delete every occurrence where `Publication date` = `Date + 1` so when `Publication Date` = `2018-12-12` and `Date` = `2018-12-11` all of those values are dropped.

It would look like:

```
 Publication Date       Date  Value State
       2018-12-12 2018-12-12   12.0    AL
       2018-12-12 2018-12-12   13.0    AZ
       2018-12-12 2018-12-12   14.0    AK
       2018-12-12 2018-12-12   12.0    NJ
       2018-12-12 2018-12-12   11.5    NY
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a mask, use it to filter `df`:

```
m = df['Publication Date'].eq(df['Date'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='D'))
df[~m]

  Publication Date       Date  Value State
5       2018-12-12 2018-12-12   12.0    AL
6       2018-12-12 2018-12-12   13.0    AZ
7       2018-12-12 2018-12-12   14.0    AK
8       2018-12-12 2018-12-12   12.0    NJ
9       2018-12-12 2018-12-12   11.5    NY
```

If "Publication Date" and "Date" are not date time columns, use [`pd.to_datetime(..., errors='coerce')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to coerce them first.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
df[(df.Publication-df.Date).dt.days!=1]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, please import timedelta

```
from datetime import timedelta
```

First convert datatype of date column to datetime.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df["Publication Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Publication Date"])
```

Then filter dataframe

```
df = df[df["Publication Date"] != df.date + timedelta(days=1)];
```

Comment: Pandas has pd.datetime and pd.TimeDelta. Example pd.datetime.now(), or pd.Timedelta('4 days 1 hr 32 s'). It appears that datetime is enherited :) so you don't need to import it :)